# Expandable List Doesn't Expand if I have Formatted and Added things to Parent Header XML File

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview

I have designed an ExpandableListView, which was expanding fine until after I added an ImageView, View (Vert. Line), and Button to the parent item.

Parent XML Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:background="#B9B9B9"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chooseNgo_listParent_ngoLogo_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/chooseNgo_listParent_verticalLine_view"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chooseNgo_listParent_ngoLogo_imageView"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chooseNgo_listParent_selectNgo_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#B9B9B9"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/chooseNgo_listParent_selectNgo_button"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseNgo_listParent_listHeader_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        />
```

It doesn't work in the above setup. It works if I only have this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:background="#B9B9B9"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseNgo_listParent_listHeader_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure why is this. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell we what do you required in the parent and the child layout 
and on which  view click do you want to expand your parent?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me, when he clicks on the parent list item, it should expand. Am I having some error where the relativelayout is covering the whole linearlayout, thats why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the button in your parent layout consuming the click event, 
Add these two lines and your code will run perfectly

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: But my button doesn't have any listener. Will that make a difference?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as button itself refer from its name as an entity which is must be click, so it attains the focus, or in other words we would say that the priority of focus is higher for a button as compared to the rest of the views, whereas adding listener is only to capture the click event to perform some additional task

Comment: Oh okay thanks! And do you know how to disable the arrows on the expanded list view? The default ones

Comment: mListView.setGroupIndicator(null);

Comment: What if I do want to use that button though? Like if i set it false for focusable and clickable, I wont be able to use the button at all right?

Comment: its not possible as the system will not recognize the ambiguous click event, but perhaps the same can be achieve using ImageView

Comment: Never mind I got it. Thanks a lot! I just set it to only focusable false, but left clickable as true.